# Jasmine throws an exception when done is called at the end of my test case and does not proceed to next test case

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine

At the end of my test, jasmine throws an exception and does not proceed to the next test case. Everything in the test function executes okay until when jasmine calls the done function.

```
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at process.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at process.exit (node.js:750:17)
    at Jasmine.module.exports [as exit] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine/lib/exit.js:6:5)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:160:23
    at jasmineDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine/lib/reporters/exit_code_reporter.js:10:5)
    at dispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1966:28)
    at ReportDispatcher.jasmineDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1949:11)
```

test code:

```
describe('trace:', function () { 
    it('Can log trace message', function (done) {
        console.log('###### Can log trace message');
        expect(true).toBe(true);
        done();
    }, 20000);
});
```

Comment: could you share your test code?

Comment: This is my code here for the single describe block: <br/>

Comment: <pre>describe('trace:', function () {

    it('Can log trace message', function () {
      console.log('###### Can log trace message');
      expect(true).toBe(true);
    }, 20000);
  });</pre>

Comment: what is the reported error? Before the stack trace that you pasted.

This seems to be a problem with your local setup, if you test your code on jsfiddle, it works. See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6pfehx0/2/)

Comment: All I get is this: Trace: About to exit with code: 1